# Eclipse doesn't recognize jar method

Tags: java, eclipse

I am struggling with a very strange issue (eclipse mars.1)

I have a jar which I am using its methods.
 I have added a new method to the class I use, created a new jar, refreshed the client project, I CAN SEE the new methods in the client project explorer, but I cannot use them in the client code!!! I can use only the old methods! It is making me crazy!!

Please see image:
[image: error case]

In case image was not uploaded, the error message I get is: "The method initLog(String) is undefined for the type Log4jWrapper"

```
public void init(String a_strPropertiesPath){

Log4jWrapper.initLog("aaa"); //doesn't recognize initLog
}


public void log(LogLevelEnum a_level, String a_sMethodName, String a_sMessage){
Log4jWrapper.writeLog(a_level, a_sMessage); //recognizes writeLog
}
```

Thank you all!

Comment: Are you sure you are using that Log4jWrapper ?

Comment: show the import please. is the jar in your build path? Have you restarted eclipse?

Comment: @Stultuske I have added code to my question

Comment: @Simo It is. I can use other methods. And yes, I restarted eclipse.

Comment: you still haven't shown the imports.

Comment: @eis How can I show you? I can assure that the jar is in the Java build path. Do you mean something else?

Comment: The import in your class. Have to tried to clean the projects in eclipse? Are you using maven?

Comment: Is "project" -  "build automatically" checked?

Comment: @Simo The imort is simply the import to the class: import com.load.log.Log4jWrapper; Yes, it is Maven and I performed clean. But the import is not a dependency but a regular jar import.

Comment: But the package in your image is com.att.load.log ....

Comment: @dushkin: we're just trying to figure out whether it is pointing to a second Log4jWrapper class on your path

Comment: @Simo yes, that's ok. It was just a naive attempt to hide the company name :-) The path in the image is the correct one and I am using it correctly.

Comment: You can remove the lib and check if there are the expected compiler errors. If not there is perhaps another jar ....

Comment: Did you find the error? :-)

Comment: @Simo I think you are right. I removed the jar, and still only one error appears. I will check!

Comment: @Simo Yes! You were right! I had a multiple import of the same jar. The second one was imported automatically as eclipse, for some reason, added an import of the whole folder where the jar is placed (WHY???). Thank you all guys for your help. If you can add your advice as an answer, I can mark it as complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple imports of the same jar in your classpath :-)

Comment: Do you have an idea, why when I am importing an external jar, I see the whole containing folder under the project tree in the project explorer?

Comment: you can hide ressources in the package explorer of eclipse. I this the goal?

Comment: Ok, but that it mean that it imports all the jars in this folder?

Comment: no, you have to add the jar explicit to the build path.